# How to resolve Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] in NodeJS GET/POST request

Tags: node.js

I built in Node 2 methods to GET and to POST for profiles and when I do the requests I get:
`Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

I added also a centralized way to handle errors and I'm not sure if it is that which causes the error. By the way, the GET or POST are not failing I can see the results and send the records to the DB but I see on the console the above error.

The methods:

```
// Profile model
const { Profile } = require("../models");
const { ErrorHandlers } = require("../utilities");

// Profiles Controller
const ProfilesController = {
    // To GET ALL the profiles
    async getAll(req, res, next) {
        try {
            // Profiles from DB & count how many
            const profiles = await Profile.find({});
            const profilesCount = await Profile.countDocuments();

            // No profiles from DB then error via handler
            if (profiles.length === 0) {
                throw new ErrorHandlers.ErrorHandler(
                    404,
                    "No profiles have been found"
                );
            }
            // Sending response with results
            res.status(200).json({ count: profilesCount, profiles });
            // Passing the error to the error-handling middleware in server.js
            next();
        } catch (err) {
            // Internal server error
            next(err);
        }
    },

    // To Create a new profile
    async createNew(req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.body);
        // Profile init
        const profile = new Profile({
            ...req.body
        });

        try {
            // Await the save
            const newProfile = await profile.save();
            // If save fail send error via handler
            if (!newProfile) {
                throw new ErrorHandlers.ErrorHandler(
                    400,
                    "Profile cannot be saved"
                );
            }

            // All OK send the response with results
            res.status(201).json({ message: "New profile added", newProfile });
            next();
        } catch (err) {
            // Errors
            next(err);
        }
    }
};

module.exports = ProfilesController;
```

The error handler:

```
class ErrorHandler extends Error {
    constructor(statusCode, message) {
        super();
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.message = message;
    }
}

const handleError = (err, res) => {
    const { statusCode, message } = err;
    res.status(statusCode).json({
        status: "error",
        statusCode,
        message
    });
};
module.exports = {
    ErrorHandler,
    handleError
};
```

The error handler also has a middleware that is called in server.js

```
const { ErrorHandlers } = require("../utilities");

const errors = (err, req, res, next) => {
    return ErrorHandlers.handleError(err, res);
};

module.exports = errors;
```

I cannot understand what is causing this error and I hope for an explanation about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're issue is that you're calling `next` after you call `res.someMethod`.

When you call `res.status().json()`, you tell `express` to end the request and respond with some status and a `JSON` payload. Calling `next` will invoke the next middleware in stack, but since you're "ending" the request with `res.someMethod`, there will be no "next" middleware.

Change your code in `getAll` and `createNew` by getting rid of the `next()` calls:

```js
async getAll(req, res, next) {
  // ...
  res.status(200).json(...)
},

async createNew(req, res, next) {
  // ...
  res.status(201).json(...)
}
```

Don't call `next` and `res.someMethod` at the same time. Only use `next` if you want to call the next middleware in stack or `res.someMethod` when you want to end the request and return something to whoever made the request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I used this article to make the error handler
https://dev.to/nedsoft/central-error-handling-in-express-3aej
Could you please take a look becasue it is writing to use next() and maybe I understood wrong as I'm new in this. If you could take a look at the article and help me a sec I will be glad :)

Comment: @Jakub did you try my solution? and I am only seeing him call `next` if his `if` statement doesn't execute... if you do `if (someCondition) { return res.status(...) }` then this is fine - `next` will never get called because of the `return` statement, which prevents executing everything that's below it. That's not what you're doing in your code.

Comment: Yes, I see then yes I got rid of the next all working fine without. I thought I should use like in the article. Now, all ok thanks then :)

Comment: @Jakub in the article, he has is as `if (someCondition) { return res.status }`, then on next line he calls `next()`, but if `someCondition` evaluates to `true` and he calls `res.status` the `return` statement will end this request - `next` will only get called if `someCondition` evaluates to `false` and `res.status` will not. In your code you're doing `res.status(...)` and then trying to call `next()` - which is why you're having issues. Also please vote the answer up - thanks.